# API Connector requires manifest file. Where to get it?

Tags: javascript, java, api, rest, jar

I am trying to use an integration tool to ingest data from an API, for example: `api-api-api.com/v2/user-details` that should get data like user `id`, `age`, `email`, etc.

But, it also requires some manifest file. Do you know what should it include? Maybe you have a template or an example of it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: "_it also requires some manifest file_" = I assume "_it_" refers to the integration tool. What tool, specifically (if that is relevant)? What makes you say it also requires "_some manifest file_"? Are you getting an error? If so, what error? What code causes the error? See [mre].

Comment: Which tag is relevant? `javascript`? `java`? Maybe not both. Can you edit the question to clarify?